# Как передать переменную в функцию из другого js файла

Tags: javascript, node.js

Допустим у меня есть два файла: `1.js` и `2.js`.

В первом файле, в коллбеке, я вызываю функцию из второго:

`...
var json = JSON.stringify({});
2.someFunction(json);
...`

Почему в этом случае во втором файле в функции я получаю `undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.js:

```
var f1 = function() {
  return function(message) {
    console.log('i am new function, created inside function from 1.js')
    console.log(String(message));
  }
} 


module.exports = f1();
```

2.js:

```
var f1 = require('./1');

(function somefunc(callback, message) {
  callback(message);
})(f1, 'this string from 2.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

1.js:

```
var f1 = function() {
  console.log('1.js');
} 


module.exports = f1;
```

2.js:

```
var f1 = require('./1');

(function somefunc(callback) {
  callback();
})(f1);
```

node 8.4.0

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а можно сделать так чтобы новая переменная создавалась в функции f1, и передавалась бы в коллбек какой-нибудь функции из файла 2.js.?

Comment: @НикитаБулыгин можно, но для этого мне придётся ещё раз ответить.

Comment: Здорово, а вы не можете ответить еще раз ?